# Overlap in Paired-end Reads for Sequencing?

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, genome, sequence-analysis, genome-sequencing

Regarding Sequencing:

Do/can the paired-end reads have overlaps?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the insert size is smaller than the read sizes, this would happen. For some applications, for example SNP detection for molecular diagnostics purposes, this approach is used.